# linear subsets of linear space

Tags: vector-spaces, symplectic-linear-algebra

Need help with graduate level work. I've been out of undergrad for almost 20 years.  The  problem says: Given $B$, a subset of a linear space $L$, $q$ element of $L$ and $p$ a point of $B$ such that when $q$ is a linear combination of points in $B$, the coefficient of $p$ is not $0$. Let $B'$ be the set obtained by replacing $p$ with $q$.  Then $B'$ also spans $L$.

Is this just asking me to show that $p$ allows me to form a different linear combination which will also spans $L$ since $p$ is a part of the subset which spans $L$?

If so, How do I approach proving this?

Comment: What is the set that spans $L$ when you talk about $B$ also spanning $L$?  The problem statement could be clearer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

(I think the  omitted  assumption is that $B$ spans $L$.) Starting with  the given assumption 
$q = cp+\sum c_i b_i$ (for some scalars $c_i$ and some $b_i\in B$), write $$p=c^{-1}q-\sum c^{-1}c_i b_i \tag{1}$$ Using (1), you can eliminate $p$ from any linear combination in which it appears. Thus, anything that can be written as a linear combination of elements of $B$ can also be written as a linear combination of elements of $B'$.